# What does HEAD~n^k does on git?

Tags: git, version-control, git-show

I notice that one can specify ancestors of actual commit by using the `^` or the `~` character. For example, if I have the following log of commits

```
* 1990f31 Somme third commit message 
* k135145 Somme second commit message 
* 2c13521 Somme first commit message
```

then I can know which is the parent commit of `1990f31` with `HEAD^1` (or equivalently with `HEAD~1`), which is `k135145`.

Now, I also [read](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection#Ancestry-References) that one can combine `^` or `~`  when it is a merge commit. Therefore, could someone provide an example to illustrate commit references when typing `git show HEAD~n^k` or alternatively by commuting this operators like `git show HEAD^k~n`?, where I'm considering `n` and `k` as abstractions to represent a positive integer.

Comment: See https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+tilde+caret

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`~` and `^` are operators which you can use to designate any ancestor within a commit's history.

Let us start with a diagram :

```
* aa (HEAD, master) commit
* bb merged branch `some/feature` into master
|\
| * cc (some/feature) feature: completed
| * dd feature: wip
| * ff feature: start
* | gg some fix on master
|/
* hh some commit on master
```

- `~` will go up the chain of *first* parents :

  - `aa~` is `bb`, `aa~2` is `gg`, `aa~3` is `hh`
  - `cc~` is `dd`, `cc~2` is `ff`, `cc~3` is also `hh`
  - but using `~` alone, and starting from `aa`, you will not be able to explore the `some/feature` branch : at the merge point (`bb`), `cc` is the *second* parent of `bb`
  - note that `~n` is a shortcut to `~~...~` repeated n times, eg : `aa~3` is the same as `aa~~~`
- `^` will only go up one level, but allows you to inspect the `n-th` parent for commits that have several parents

  - calling `xx^` is the same as `xx~` : in both case, it is the first parent of `xx`
  - `aa` is a regular commit, with one single parent: so `aa^` is `bb` (same as `aa~`), `aa^2` does not exist
  - `bb` is a merge commit, with 2 parents: `bb^` is `gg` (same as `bb~`), `bb^2` is `cc`, `bb^3` does not exist
  - note that `^n` is *not* a shortcut to `^^...^`, e.g :
    `bb^2` is the second parent of `bb` (it is `cc`)
    `bb^^` is the first parent of the first parent of `bb` (it is `hh`)

In some cases, you can have octopus merge commits, which may have `xx^3`, `xx^4` ... parents.

---

By combining the operators, you can "navigate" to any ancestor commit.

For example, starting from `aa`, one way to reach `ff` is :

```
aa~^2~2

# some other ways to describe a path to reach `ff` :
aa^^2~2   # to reach the first parent, ~ or ^ are equivalent
aa~^2~~   # ~2 is the same as ~~
aa^^2^^
...
```

In general, you can't switch `~` and `^` sequences, because they would not point at the same commit.
For example :

```
aa~^2   # points at cc
aa^2~   # does not exist
```

---

Anything that point to a commit can take the palce of `aa`, `bb` or `cc` above :

- `HEAD`, a `sha1`, `some/branch`, `some/tag` ...
- some other refs known to git : `stash@{0}` (items in the stash), `HEAD@{3}` (elements in the reflog of `HEAD`), `master@{2}` (elements in the reflog of the `master` branch)
- ...

Answer (score 4):

`HEAD` is always where you are. `HEAD~n` means the nth revision going back (always taking first parent). `HEAD~n^k` means, from that nth revision back from `HEAD`, take the kth parent (`HEAD~n` being a merge revision with at least k parents).